# Getting a return from the terminal in c

Tags: c, lxterminal

I am building a project which uses the raspberry pi as an embedded PC. In short the device is a data logger which records data and then downloads to a memory stick.

Most of the programming is being carried out in C. I am currently interacting with the terminal using the system() command, such as:

```
system("mount /dev/sda1 /media/usbstick -o uid=pi,gid=pi")
```

However, I would like to have some sort of error checking on the responses from the commands to the terminal. I can't think of a good way to do this, and a search didn't provide any useful answers. The error checking will be to simply light a warning LED if something has gone wrong. Can anyone think of a way I could do this?

Comment: Why not just check the value returned by system?  man system.

Comment: A question about getting help for error-checking code would be better suited for [so] - as that's a Programming-centric Stack Exchange site. Then you could come back here and ask about the LED.

Comment: Looking back, I think you are probably right about it being in the wrong section. I just put it here because it was a problem I encountered on the Pi, but agree it's not specific to the Pi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am currently interacting with the terminal using the system() command, such as

Don't do that.  All of those commands are implemented in C in the first place and are open source.  Many of them are just wrappers on system calls.

```
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <stdio>
#include <string>
#include <errno.h>

if (mount (
    "/dev/sda1",
    "/media/usbstick",
    "vfat",
    0,
    "uid=1000,gid=1000"
) == -1) puts(strerror(errno));
else puts("Okay.");
```

Errors and usage are explained in `man 2 mount`<sup>1</sup> <- note the **2** here; that's the *system calls* section of the manual system  (see `man man` for more about sections).  You have to use numbers with the uid/gid argument; you can get those with `getpwnam`:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>

struct passwd *info = getpwnam("pi");
printf("UID is %d\n", info->pw_uid);
```

More in `man getpwnam` (you don't need 2 this time since there's nothing in section 1 by that name).  You can find stuff like this with, e.g.:

```
apropos -s 2,3 uid
```

See `man apropos` if you don't know about that.  `-s 2,3` is check only sections 2 (system calls) and 3 (library functions) to avoid including a long list of section 1, etc. stuff.

If you absolutely want to invoke another executable and process its output (which is much more of an awkward hassle than a system call such as `mount()`, not to mention much much much less efficient) see **`man popen`**, which returns a `FILE*` to the process's stdin or stdout.

---

<sup>1. E.g., if you change the fs type to `ext4` you'll get an EINVAL because your options (`uid=`...) are not valid for that type.  You do need to specify the type; you'll get EINVAL if that's wrong too.  The easiest way if you don't know it is probably to try an array of them testing for EINVAL.</sup>

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice, it's really useful. I'll let you know how it turns out!